# Give an example of Java code that would not compile due to type erasure

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Generics use type erasure to remove the type at runtime and this is how we implement parametric polymorphism in Java but I can't seem to come up with example code that wouldn't compile due to type erasure. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `public void type(){ }`  with type erasure, this would not compile.

Comment: Although, I struggle to understand why a compiler would remove all instances of the string "type" in the source code.  In all seriousness though, we are not a coding service, nor a homework generator.

Answer (score 1):

This for instance:

```
public void method(Object o) {
    ...
}

public <T> void method(T t) {
    ...
}
```

Because the erasure of `T` is `Object` the method signature ends up being the same, and you can't have multiple methods with the same signature. It fails compilation with the error:

```
error: name clash: <T>method(T) and method(Object) have the same erasure
    public <T> void method(T t) {
                    ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>method(T)
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a generic array like `T[] array` where `T` is a generic type.